# Escape characters in private key for sed replace

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I need to replace the string $ssh_private_key_contents within a config.yaml file with the actual ssh private key content (each line of the key separated by \n).

```
$ssh_private_key_contents="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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\nqNUWH8qPzaXEJ74ADUupv5ukkpA6zWVg9e4VNDG0cpwZmRBcSIY=\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n"

sed -i 's/$ssh_private_key_contents/'"$ssh_private_key_contents"'/g' config.yaml
```

I got this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 81: unknown option to `s'
```

I tried escaping the / but kept getting more errors. The actual config file has different kinds of such strings that need to be populated.

Comment: this is not a direct solution since it is not about escaping, but you can use any character instead of '/' as delimiter, so something like `sed -i 's!hoo!bar!g'` or `sed -i 's#hoo#bar#g'` is legitimate. therefore if you can assume that '!' or '#' never occurs in `$ssh_private_key_contents`, use it as delimiter.

Comment: Does $ssh_private_key_contents contain actual newline characters, or just backslashes followed by newlines? And if the latter, do thy need to be translated into actual newlines in the substitution?

Comment: @Langali for future reference, there's no need to post your RSA private key in the sample source code (and I recommend against it); it's sufficient to say: `ssh_private_key_contents="----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----\n...."` and folks will understand. In this particular case, the interesting information is what characters appear in the key, but not the key itself. Also, at this point, I would recommend that you generate a new RSA key.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As ymonad said in the comments, assuming that `%` does not appear in the SSH private key, you can use:

```bash
sed -i "s%\$ssh_private_key%$ssh_private_key%" config.yaml
```

Alternatively, choose any other character that does not appear in the contents of `$ssh_private_key`.

Also, consider whether you want to escape the `\` in the output or whether you want the `\n` to become real newlines in the output.